# IIS mgr not listed in Admin Tools

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7 Ultra. Trying to install IIS 7 following procedure to change windows features by checking CGI box in IIS. Get the install dialog but disappears without any success validation. Furthermore, I do not find the inetmgr listed in the Admin Tools dialog. It seems that IIS install did not complete properly. Looking for some help as to what direction I must persue.

Answer (score 0):

To use `inetmgr.exe` you have to turn this feature on first. In the GUI: Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > Web Management Tools